# WordPress page.php and page-{slug}.php

Tags: php, wordpress

When I have both page.php and page-{slug}.php files, what can I write in page.php?
I executed live site with blank page.php then it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When slug match, page-{slug}.php will be used.

Ex:

```
Page url: site/register
```

If page-register.php exist, it will be used.

If not exist, page.php will be used.

I often used page-{slug}.php to create the customize page ( register, subscribe...)

page.php should be used to handle to render the content of page in wordpress.

Comment: Thank you, is page.php is necessary or only page-{slug}.php can work?

Comment: It's depend on your purpose, it might be needless if your wordpress only use post or page-{slug}... But page.php should exist for best practice... even though it's empty

Comment: Glad it's help. welcome to stackoverflow, when you find an helpful answer, please upvote/accept the answer, it will be a motive for answers.